# Problem with sending pictures to icloud

Tags: icloud

I have icloud which is almost empty, because my phone does not send pictures to icloud. It has sent only 88 pictures and rest of them are in the phone, and I cannot take pictures anymore because I dont have place. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Answer (score 1):

on your iPhone go to settings and tap the top button with your name. On the screen that comes up tap icloud. On next screen tap Photos. On that screen make sure 'iCloud Photo library' is on and make sure 'Optimize iPhone Storage' is checked. Then wait awhile as photos are moved to icloud.